# How to install chatterbot in google colab

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, chatbot, chatterbot

I plan to install Chatterbot in Google Colab, but I have been unable to install it.

I have been getting errors when using `!pip install chatterbot` directly. Below are screenshots of my code and the error message.

```
!pip install chatterbot

Collecting chatterbot
  Downloading ChatterBot-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 67.8/67.8 kB 2.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting mathparse<0.2,>=0.1 (from chatterbot)
  Downloading mathparse-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (7.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: nltk<4.0,>=3.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from chatterbot) (3.8.1)
Collecting pint>=0.8.1 (from chatterbot)
  Downloading Pint-0.22-py3-none-any.whl (294 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 294.0/294.0 kB 11.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pymongo<4.0,>=3.3 (from chatterbot)
  Downloading pymongo-3.13.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (516 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 516.2/516.2 kB 49.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting python-dateutil<2.8,>=2.7 (from chatterbot)
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (225 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 225.7/225.7 kB 24.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pyyaml<5.2,>=5.1 (from chatterbot)
  Downloading PyYAML-5.1.2.tar.gz (265 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 265.0/265.0 kB 29.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error`
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You need to install python 3.8 separately to use chatterbot.

From your error I can see that you are using `python 3.10`

However, chatterbot only supports `Python >=3.4, <=3.8`

**Link to document : https://pypi.org/project/ChatterBot/**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Installing ChatterBot in Google Colab requires installing several dependencies, and sometimes there might be issues due to the limitations of the Colab environment. However, you can try the following steps to install ChatterBot in Google Colab:

python
!pip install chatterbot
!pip install chatterbot_corpus
Additionally, you might need to install the pytz library:

python
!pip install pytz
After installing these libraries, you can use ChatterBot in your Colab notebook:

python
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

## Create a new chat bot

chatbot = ChatBot('MyBot')

## Create a new trainer for the chat bot

trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)

## Train the chat bot on the English language corpus data

trainer.train('chatterbot.corpus.english')

## Test the chat bot

response = chatbot.get_response('Hello, how are you?')
print(response)

These commands should work in most cases, but keep in mind that Google Colab environments can sometimes have restrictions on certain libraries or versions. If you encounter any issues, you might need to explore alternative approaches or consider running your code in a different environment.

Comment: Are you aware of our [policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?

Comment: Not helpful. The problem is somewhere in the incpompability of the colab servers.